# Why does this function not work in python 2.7 but work fine in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am not sure why the function keeps returning 4 for all values of n when run with python 2.7, it works fine in 3.6.
For example: aproxpi(1) should be 2.6666, and aproxpi(2) should be 3.466666.

```
x = 1
y = 0
pi = 0
def aproxpi(n):
    global x, y, pi
    if n <= 0:
        if y % 2 == 0:
            pi += (float(1 / x))
        else:
            pi -= (float(1 / x))
        x = 1
        y = 0
        pi2 = pi
        pi = 0
        return 4 * pi2
    n -= 1
    if y % 2 == 0:
        y += 1
        pi += (float(1 / x))
        x += 2
    else:
        y += 1
        pi -= (float(1 / x))
        x += 2
    return aproxpi(n)
```

Comment: Works fine in 3.6.4, cannot reproduce. Side note, no need for the `globals`, just define in scope.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "define in scope", in new to python and I don't get what that means. Thanks

Comment: It means that you don't to define them like global variables, since these variables are only used in function. Declare them like this if you want : `x, y, pi = 1, 0, 0`

Comment: Other than that. It's not a good idea to `return aproxpi(n)` unless you want to have a recursive function.

Answer (score 6):

You are running this program in Python 2, where division is integer division by default.

Add this line to the beginning of the program:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This will make division be closer to what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I managed to fix it by just replacing.     pi -= (float(1 / x)) with pi -= 1.0/x

Comment: @Mustafa I strongly recommend migrating to Python 3; Python 2 picked up many design flaws as it evolved and most of them were fixed in Python 3, so you'll have far fewer things like this to keep in mind all the time.

Comment: yea I use python 3 mostly, but my teacher insists on using python 2 so I have to make sure the code works in Python 2 before submitting it.

Comment: @Mustafa You might find the `six` module useful. If you can't use it because it's not in the standard library, add `from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, absolute_import, division, generators, nested_scopes, with_statement` at the beginning of your to increase compatibility with Python 3. (You'll still have problems with `raw_input` and `xrange` but if you alias these too...)

Comment: Man I owe you a beer for this. I was wondering why it was working in Python 3 but not 2. Thanks!